# AspectJExpressionPointcut uses wrong classLoader

Tags: java, osgi, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a Java EE application consisting of multiple OSGi bundles running within Apache Felix container. One of these bundles is responsible for loading Spring application context.
I'm using Spring AOP in my application and the following error arised in my bundle:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.somepackage.SomeClass [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:206)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:192)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
```

The cause of this problem is that class(com.somepackage.SomeClass) used in pointcat of my aspect was loaded by bundle ClassLoader but AspectJExpressionPointcut passes default ClassLoader to buildPointcutExpression() method:

```
private void checkReadyToMatch() {
    if (getExpression() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match");
    }
    if (this.pointcutExpression == null) {
        this.pointcutClassLoader = (this.beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableBeanFactory ?
                ((ConfigurableBeanFactory) this.beanFactory).getBeanClassLoader() :
                ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader());
        this.pointcutExpression = buildPointcutExpression(this.pointcutClassLoader);
    }
}
```

which knows nothing about this class (com.somepackage.SomeClass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing ClassLoader in thread initializing Spring Application Context:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(bundleClassLoader);
```

So method ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader() returns bundleClassLoader which can load class mentioned in pointcut.

Comment: Great news that you have solved your own problem. On StackOverflow it is perfectly okay to accept your own answer in order to close the question. Please do so. Thanks.