# Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aspects

When I was trying to solve this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614073/afterthrowing-not-work-as-expected)...

I faced

```
Must set property 'expression' before attempting to match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was, that I had no value for pointcut in `@AfterThrowing` annotation:

**wrong**

```
@AfterThrowing(throwing = "ex")
public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
    //throw DatabaseException
    System.out.println("DAE");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("DAE");
}

@AfterThrowing(throwing = "ex")
public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
    //throw ServiceException
    System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("RE");
}
```

**correct**

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void intercept(DataAccessException ex) throws Exception {
    //throw DatabaseException
    System.out.println("DAE");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("DAE");
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void intercept(RuntimeException ex) throws Exception {
    //throw ServiceException
    System.out.println("RE - " + ex.getClass());
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("RE");
}
```

Similar question I found was [AspectJExpressionPointcut uses wrong classLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275837/aspectjexpressionpointcut-uses-wrong-classloader), but I was not dealing with class loader problem...